# Matching When Value Is List

Tags: jq

I have an API dump file that is similar to this.

```
{
  "abc": {
    "Code": "ABC",
    "Type": []  },
  "def": {
    "Code": "DEF",
    "Type": [
      "A"
    ]
  },
  "ghi": {
    "Code": "GHI",
    "Type": [
      "B"
    ]
  },
  "jkl": {
    "Code": "JKL",
    "Type": [
      "A",
      "B"
    ]
  },
   "mno": {
    "Code": "MNO",
    "Type": [ "Universal" ]
  }
}
```

I am trying to extract objects, and get Code keys based on certain Type matches.

For example.
Trying to where Type matches "A", "B", "A, B", or Universal, I am getting objects that contain both, or nothing in certain cases.

Here is what I tried.

```
jq -r '.[] | select(.Type[] == "A") | .Code' /tmp/test.json
```

I get

> DEF 
> JKL

Which is unexpectedly matching Type ["A"} and Type ["A", "B"]

```
jq -r '.[] | select(.Type[] == "B") | .Code' /tmp/test.json
```

I get.

> GHI 
> JKL

Which is unexpectedly matching Type ["B"} and Type ["A", "B"]

```
jq -r '.[] | select(.Type[] == "A, B") | .Code' /tmp/test.json
```

Matches nothing.

This works as expected.

```
jq -r '.[] | select(.Type[] == "Universal") | .Code' /tmp/test.json
```

> MNO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted exact match, save following into `script.jq` :

```
.[] | select(.Type == $match) | .Code
```

Then test with

```
$ jq -r --argjson match '["A"]' -f script.jq test.json
DEF
$ jq -r --argjson match '["B"]' -f script.jq test.json
GHI
$ jq -r --argjson match '["A", "B"]' -f script.jq test.json
JKL
```

Comment: Works as expected. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The jq program

.[] | select(any(.Type[]; IN("A","B","A, B","Universal"))) | .Code

produces:

```
"DEF"
"GHI"
"JKL"
"MNO"
```

Comment: As explained I am using jq, but the goal was matching exactly for each type, not all of them. 
Also, the version of jq I have does not understand "IN", probably compiled without it . I get "jq: error: IN/1 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1" when running your suggestion. Thanks for responding. I appreciate the time and the effort.

Comment: IN has been available as a built-in function since jq 1.5 i.e. August 2015 (!).